# Problems with promotion page on Prestashop 1.7.3.0

Tags: php, prestashop, promotions

I'm using prestashop 1.7.3.0 for e-commerce and i've got problems with the promotions page.

in fact, the page show some products but they aren't in the shop that they normally should be in.

On this page, some products are displayed despite having no active promotion on that shop. They are promoted on another shop of this same prestashop instance.
I don't think it is a normal behaviour for that page.

the page herself is more demonstrative :https://renault-brie.commander-mes-accessoires.fr/promotions

There is a prices-drop.tpl and a pricesdropcontroller.php that they control this promotion page but i'm seeking for help.

Do you have any clues ? Anyone that encounters these issues?

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here

<pre><code>


`prices-drop.tpl

{extends file='catalog/listing/product-list.tpl'}



PricesDropController.php


<?php
/**
 * 2007-2017 PrestaShop
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * https://opensource.org/licenses/OSL-3.0
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@prestashop.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade PrestaShop to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize PrestaShop for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.prestashop.com for more information.
 *
 * @author    PrestaShop SA <contact@prestashop.com>
 * @copyright 2007-2017 PrestaShop SA
 * @license   https://opensource.org/licenses/OSL-3.0 Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * International Registered Trademark & Property of PrestaShop SA
 */
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Product\Search\ProductSearchQuery;
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Product\Search\SortOrder;
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\PricesDrop\PricesDropProductSearchProvider;

class PricesDropControllerCore extends ProductListingFrontController
{
    public $php_self = 'prices-drop';

    /**
     * Initializes controller.
     *
     * @see FrontController::init()
     *
     * @throws PrestaShopException
     */
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->doProductSearch('catalog/listing/prices-drop');
    }
q

    protected function getProductSearchQuery()
    {
        $query = new ProductSearchQuery();
        $query
            ->setQueryType('prices-drop')
            ->setSortOrder(new SortOrder('product', 'name', 'asc'))
        ;

        return $query;
    }

    protected function getDefaultProductSearchProvider()
    {
        return new PricesDropProductSearchProvider(
            $this->getTranslator()
        );
    }

    public function getListingLabel()
    {
        return $this->trans(
            'On sale',
            array(),
            'Shop.Theme.Catalog'
        );
    }
}
`
</code></pre>`
```